# Why isn't my :nth-child selector working?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a very easy example:

```
<div class="capa4">
    <div class="micapa4 capa41">LA 41</div>
    <div class="micapa4 capa42">LA 42</div>
    <div class="capa43">Ampliar</div>
</div>
```

I want to click "capa43" and hide "capa42" and expand "capa41".

```
.capa43:active .capa4:nth-child(1) { width:100%; }

.capa43:active .capa4:nth-child(2) { display:none; }
```

But this doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `.capa43` is not parent of `capa4:nth-child(1)` or `.capa4:nth-child(2)` . And `div` have no `:active` pseudoclass. Try to use some other markup structure, using links where needed

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan actually, not only links have `:active` pseudo-classes now ;) (since IE8) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active

Comment: sounds like a job for a hacked radio button control, or alternatively js to achieve this.

Comment: nice to know but still not so confident to start using it on a div (IE8 is still around)

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan it **does** work in IE8. It's IE7 that's not supported. Tbh I haven't had a need to use `:active` on those kind of element in practice, but `:hover` for example is quite useful (and it's supported on IE>=7 so even better)

Comment: good, something new learnt: that's why I like SO :)

Answer (score 3):

You've confused a couple of things here.

Firstly,

```
.capa43:active .capa4 {}
```

This selector selects all `.capa4` elements that are a ***descendant*** of the `.capa43` class that is in an `:active` state. It's not *'When `.capa43` is active, find `.capa4` elements and style them.'* It's all about relation. What you are trying here is commonly referred to as a 'parent selector', which does not exist in CSS.

Secondly,

`:nth-child` works on the element itself, not the parent. It asks *'Am I the Nth child of my parent?'*.

To make this work with pure CSS, you'd need to restructure your HTML, and use sibling selectors.

```css
.capa43:active ~ .micapa4:nth-child(2) {
  color: red;
}
.capa43:active ~ .micapa4:nth-child(3) {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="capa4">
  <div class="capa43">Ampliar</div>
  <div class="micapa4 capa41">LA 41</div>
  <div class="micapa4 capa42">LA 42</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to answer your question. I didn't test myself, but it should work.

[Change css style of an element by clicking another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18059940/change-css-style-of-an-element-by-clicking-another)

css:

```
    #d2:target {
        display: none;
    }
```

html:

```
    <div id="d1">
      Text
    <div id="d2">Word
      <a href="#d2">My other text</a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to change the order of those items a bit:

```
<div class="capa4">
    <div class="capa43">Ampliar</div>
    <div class="micapa4 capa41">LA 41</div>
    <div class="micapa4 capa42">LA 42</div>
</div>
```

then you will be able to use *next siblings* selector:

```
.capa43:active ~ .micapa4:nth-child(2) { width:100%; }
.capa43:active ~ .micapa4:nth-child(3) { display:none; }
```

Here's a working example: http://jsbin.com/qudona/3/edit?html,css,output

Comment: `div:active` won't work and `~` needs for the last rule

Comment: You're right (only in the second part ;) ), just fixed it

Comment: Heads up, your children's numbering is incorrect in both your example and demo, as per what the question was trying to do.

Comment: @Oka, oh, details, details :)